# How to extend class in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have directory is named `controllers` with classe.

There is directory `crm` in `controllers` with some classess.

How I can to extend class in `controllers` from `/crm/classHug`? where `classHug` is class (file).

I tried:

```
class Sender extends 'crm/ClassHug'
{
  // BODY
}

class Sender extends ClassHug
{
  // BODY
}
```

Comment: did you search the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a generic controller class named MY_Controller in application/core folder and it needs to inherit from CI_Controller class.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then, your controller classes must inherit from MY_Controller.

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```